# Memory error with string permutations

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory

I have this script that will calculate all permutations of a given string from a file:

```
import sys
from itertools import permutations


def find_permutations(word):
    perms = [''.join(p) for p in permutations(word)]
    return ','.join(perms)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as data:
        for line in data.readlines():
            print(find_permutations(line.rstrip()))
```

However I have run into a `Memory error` with the following string `American Pie`. Is there a way I could get all the permutations of this string without running into a memory error? Or is it truly that there are so many, the system cannot handle it?

Exact error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "string_perms.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(find_permutations(line.rstrip()))
  File "string_perms.py", line 7, in find_permutations
    return ','.join(perms)
MemoryError
```

Comment: Keep permutations as an iterator then you don't need to generate the whole list in memory

Comment: @Chris_Rands I'm still new to python, can you give man example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one tip I think would fix this is to avoid reading the entire file into memory at once since you only need one line at a time:

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as data:
    for line in data:
        for words in find_permutations(line.rstrip()):
             print(words)
```

And then you could skip creating the `perms` list entirely in your function and return a generator instead:

```
def find_permutations(word):
    return (''.join(p) for p in permutations(word))
```

On another note, I'm not sure it is of interest to include whitespaces in your permutations, otherwise you could `replace` all occurrences of those with an empty string.

Comment: `"American Pie"` has 479001600 permutations. Printing out that many permutations at once is never going to work

Comment: @Chris_Rands I apparently didn't think of that initially. Good catch, updated.

Comment: Ok, deleting my answer, as we're both saying the same thing now but your generator expression is neater. I think this is turning into an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) though

Answer (score 1):

> Or is it truly that there are so many, the system cannot handle it?

Yup.

There will be `math.factorial(len(word))` permutations of the string, and once those permutations are converted to strings and then joined with `','` into a larger string, your result is a string that's `math.factorial(len(word)) * (len(word)+1) - 1` characters long.  Even if each character only occupied one byte, that's 6227020799 bytes (6+ gigs) for the string 'American Pie'.  Furthermore, you're starting from a `list` of permutations, so double that to get a rough estimate of the *minimum* memory allocated during that function call.

The real question is *what exactly do you need to do* with each of those perms?  If you only need to use one at a time, take advantage of the fact that `permutations` is a lazy generator to begin with.

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as data:
    for line in data:
        for perm in permutations(line):
            permstr = ''.join(perm)
            print(permstr, end=',')
            #do what you need with perm here
```

If you need to access a permutation at will, you'll have to think of something more involved like only computing some permutations in chunks and saving the data to disk to be accessed later.

Comment: what I need to do is output them in this format, for example `the,teh,het,..`